# fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value (When validating the empty text field)

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to validate the empty text field, i.e. if the text field is left empty, show the alert message, but am getting the **error**:

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

This is my code:

```
 dateComponents.month = String(monthTextField.text!).toInt()!
    dateComponents.day = String(dayTextField.text!).toInt()!
    dateComponents.year = String(yearTextField.text!).toInt()!

    if self.monthTextField.text == ""{
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Month", message:
            "Please enter 2 digits in the 'mm' field, e.g. 01 for January", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
        alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Dismiss", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default,handler: nil))

        self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Comment: How is monthTextField supposed to be initialised? The message says that it hasn't been.

Comment: You have to check that self.monthTextField.text and the others are not nil. nil and "" are not the same. You need to do this **before** explicitly unwrapping them. Also, are you absolutely sure they can be converted to an Int? It is also helpful if you indicate which statement is causing the error.

Comment: The text property is defined at `text!` so it can't be nil, but the UITextField itself may be

Answer (score 1):

If `monthTextField`'s `text` property is an empty string (`""`), then the first line in the code in your question will throw the fatal error you're seeing. This is because `toInt()` will return `nil` and you're trying to force unwrap that with `!` (which will always cause a crash).

Using forced unwrapping all over like you are doing is going to be a problem. If your text fields are `nil` or have a non-numeric string in their `text` property, that's a fatal error. I would handle this by using a combination of optional binding and optional chaining to validate the text in your text fields (as well as the text fields themselves if need be). That would look something like this:

```
var monthTextFields: UITextField? // Set via code or xib or storyboard, doesn't matter

if let month = monthTextField?.text?.toInt() {
    /* month is now an Int that you can safely use */
} else {
    /* the text is not a valid Int, display your alert */
}
```

That code will not crash because it's making sure that it never unwraps a `nil` value every step of the way. What that `if` line is essentially saying is: "if `monthTextField` is not `nil` and its `text` property is not `nil` and calling `toInt()` on its `text` property doesn't return `nil`, then set `month` to the result of `toInt()`".

Answer (score 0):

An empty string is not convertible to an int. Thus, your code fails even before your if unwrapping takes place. I suggest you change your code to unwrap the integer instead of the string, and it should work.